#Linkedin Attempting to integrate LinkedIn with Bullhorn. When I add LinkedIn RSC in Bullhorn. I get the error No company ID found for viewer account
Having received the error message:
"No company ID found for viewer account
This account is not associated with any company ID. Contact LinkedIn support for further assistance."
LinkedIn support has redirected me to SO for further guidance / resolution
I have tried following the steps stipulated by Bullhorn. Their error message indicates I have to raise the issue with LinkedIn - they directed me here.
I was expecting the integration to go seamlessly.
